# Filter blog posts report in Google Analytics based on date of publish

Tags: google-analytics, blogs

Is there any way to filter the report page of Google Analytics (Behavior> Site Content> All pages) based on date of publish of blog posts.
I tried the calender on top right but it shows all the posts not the specific ones.

Comment: with a bit of creativity you can store the published date into GA servers: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually no way for Google Analytics to know when your blog posts where published, because it can't access your blog's database and pull up that information.

However, some blogging platforms insert the date into the URL. For example Wordpress: http://ac360.blogs.cnn.com/2014/11/21/american-journey-paralyzed-marine-stands-and-accepts-his-bronze-star/?hpt=ac_mid. As you can see the date is actually present inside the URL (`2014/11/21`), so if this website is using GA, its administrator can go the *Content* section of GA and filter pages based on date, for example by inputting `2014/11` to get only articles published in November 2014, or `2013/08/22` to get only articles published on August 22nd 2013.